# Laravel 5.2 - Validation Errors (How do I get the page to return to the exact point in the scroll)

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have successfully set up validation errors for my laravel 5.2 app.  But my form is at the bottom of the page.  When a validation error gets triggered, the page reloads with the error, but it goes to the top of the page.  Is there any way to have the page refresh and stay at the point in the scroll that that user had it?  Or at the point where the form is (/#calltoaction).  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope you can try the `<form action={{route('url','#calltoaction')}} method="post">`

So this will make you like 
`http://url?#calltoaction`

Answer (score 1):

That's not a Laravel issue, but a html issue.

```
<div id="calltoaction">
    // Your content here
</div>

<form action="/foo#calltoaction" method="post">
    // Your form here

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

By clicking the button, there's a POST request to `foo` and you're jumping to the div with id `calltoaction`.

Of course, you can use the route helper from Laravel instead of hard coded url.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the validation and redirection manually instead of using `$this->validate()`:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`

...

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'comment' => 'required',
    'username' => 'required',
]);

if ($v->fails()) {
    return redirect(url()->previous() . "#anchor")->withErrors($v->errors());
}
```